react-native-dotenv and nativewind cache problem
I have an application that I developed with react-native. I installed packages such as nativewind, react-native-dotenv. And I ran my application on my own device. Then I changed a few colors that I defined in the config file for nativewind. I also changed the url in my .env file. But it was not updated on my device. I deleted the data, deleted the application and reinstalled it, but the old color and url continued to appear. When I try it from a different device, the current color and URL work without any problems. I think the problem is a cache system, but I don't know how to solve it.
Thanks for your help.
I deleted the data, deleted the application and reinstalled it
